# Posting hidden field and values from C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cxml

Hi I am trying to achieve following in c# where I want to post xml data to a url where cxml-urlencoded is an hidden field.

```
<FORM METHOD=POST ACTION=<%= url%>>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME="cxml-urlencoded" VALUE="<% CreateCXML toUser,
fromUser, buyerCookie, unitPrice, supPartId, supPartAuxId, desc%>">
<INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT value=BUY>
</FORM>
```

I tried doing it

```
string  myurl=(uri+Server.UrlEncode(str1));
      Response.Write(@"<a input type=""hidden"" name=""cxml-urlencoded"" value=""myurl""></a>"); 
      Response.Close();
```

Any ideas how to best go about it?

Comment: I have no idea what the two code samples have to do with each other. What's `CreateCXML`? Where are you URL-encoding things? Where does the output of `Response.Write()` go? Why are you outputting obviously invalid HTML, with the literal `myurl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a HiddenField server control in the page

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdXML"/>
```

and set the value in the hidden fields from code behind as

```
hdXml.Value = CreateCXML(toUser, fromUser, buyerCookie, unitPrice, supPartId, supPartAuxId, desc);
```

Make sure you have the CreateCXML function declared and returning string.